# How to draw Rectangle and Circle using free hand mouse in openlayers3?

Tags: openlayers

How to draw Rectangle and Circle using free hand mouse in openlayers3 ?
I know we can draw point, lines, and Polygons. I saw this example: 
http://openlayers.org/en/master/examples/draw-features.html
but I need to draw rectangles and circles too.

Comment: Do you want to click at the center and then move the mouse to increase the size, or do you want a complete freehand drawing like in the answer below?

Comment: yes I need a complete freehand drawing like the answer below but using openalyers3

Answer (score 2):

Those who are still looking for solution can view [this](http://openlayers.org/en/master/examples/draw-features.html) URL. Here you will get the solution for drawing the circle.

```
function addInteraction() {
var value = 'Circle';
draw = new ol.interaction.Draw({
  source: source,
  type: /** @type {ol.geom.GeometryType} */ (value)
});
map.addInteraction(draw);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can check the following link which describes creating circles in OpenLayers. It doesn't mention which version it uses but perhaps you can adapt and modify it:

- [Create circles in OpenLayers using freehand mode](http://www.codechewing.com/library/create-circles-in-openlayers-using-freehand-mode/)

There's also a link to a [demo](http://www.codechewing.com/demo/openlayers/drawing-circles-freehand-mode-openlayers.html) which shows the OpenLayers script in action

Comment: It is openlayers 2 .. I used it to draw different types of polygons before but now I upgrade the website to openlayers 3 so I need to upgrade this code

Comment: Ahh ok, I found similar questions concerning freehand drawing in OpenLayers3 [here](http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.gis.openlayers.devel.ol3/2831) and [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/ol3-dev/Hxri0Qx0gPU) but don't know if they are relevant. Hopefully @DevdattaTengshe or others can provide you with a definitive answer.